# JS: click on different buttons should get printed different numbers on the screen, but it would print just one number

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I 'm in the process of creating a calculator where I have a button for each number.
When a button is pressed, depending on the id, the number gets printed on the screen. Each button adds the number pressed to that area of the screen.

This is an example of two buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="1" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros()">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="2" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros()">2</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>

<script>    
var counterAPP = {
        agregarNumeros:function(){
            var resultado = "";
            if ($("#1")) {
                resultado += $("#resultado").text("1");
            }
            else if ($("#2")) {
                resultado += $("#resultado").text("2");
            }
        }
    };
    window.APP = counterAPP;
```

Now, if I click on any of the two buttons, I get "1" printed on the screen. If I click the button (any of them) again, nothing happens.

Why is that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("#1")` will always be true value....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pass the argument in inline-function. `this.id` will send value of current elements `id` attribute.

`resultado` will be key of the `Object` and it is initialized to *0*, every time `click` takes place, `this.resultado` is incremented according to the value of the *clicked element*

`parseInt` will cast the `string` argument to `integer`

Try this:

```js
var counterAPP = {
  resultado: 0,
  agregarNumeros: function(id) {
    this.resultado += parseInt(id);
    $("#resultado").text(this.resultado);
  }
};
window.APP = counterAPP;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="1" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros(this.id)">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="2" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros(this.id)">2</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Should be

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" id="1" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros(this)">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="2" onclick="APP.agregarNumeros(this)">2</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Your script should be

```js
 var resultado = 0;
 
 var counterAPP = {
        agregarNumeros:function(e){
            
            var currValue = $(e).text();
            
            resultado += parseInt(currValue);
            
            $("#resultado").text(resultado);
           
        }
    };
    window.APP = counterAPP;
```

variable resultado is a global variable initilized to 0.

once clicking button catch the value of the pressed value using the reference passed to the function and store it in currValue variable.

add the resultado to the currValue to get the new value.

append the resultado to the div.

Find the JS Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/9ewwzmm1/